# Debugging invalid free()

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

I am writing a program in which I have to manage an array of strings. Throughout the program, the strings are systematically removed/modified until only a single string remains.

I remove the strings when they are no longer needed using this function:

```
void remove_element(char **array, int index, int array_length)
{
    int i;
    for(i = index; i < array_length - 1; i++){
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
    }
    free(array[array_length]);
}
```

Once I am totally done with the array, I use this function to ensure all the strings are free'd:

```
void free_fragments(char **frags){
    int i = 0;
    while((frags[i] != NULL) && sizeof(frags[i] != 0)){
        free(frags[i]);
        i++;
     }
    free(frags);
}
```

Yet, when I do this, valgrind gives me an "Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()" error, specifically complaining about the "free(frags[i])" line in free_fragments.

I understand that free_fragments seems kind of redundant, simply because theoretically I can call remove_element on each element until there is one remaining and then remove_element that as well, but when I try to do that, I still get a Invalid free() error, but this time complaining about remove_element. If I don't call free_fragments when I am done with the array, I get a memory leak.

My understanding of pointers is pretty beginner, so please help me debug this and improve my understanding!

Comment: I can see some potential pitfalls in your code but it's hard to pin point where the problem is without seeing the rest of your code, specially the calls to `remove_element` and `free_fragments`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that while you do `free(array[array_length]);`, you do not NULL it out, so in free_fragments you still think it is a valid pointer.
Come to think of it, you seem to free, the wrong entry, too... This should work:

```
void remove_element(char **array, int index, int array_length)
{
    int i;
    free(array[index]);
    for(i = index; i < array_length - 1; i++){
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
    }
    array[array_length-1] = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that index refers to index of string in 2d array which you want to free, I believe that there is a memory leak in your program. Wouldn't the memory address of string to be freed be lost in the first iteration: array[index] = array[index + 1].

Also you are going outside array's boundary in the last statement and freeing entirely something else. Basically there is a memory leak and you should free the string before overwriting its address with neighbouring strings as defined in @LaszloLadanyi's solution.

```
   void remove_element(char **array, int index, int array_length)
   {
        int i;
        for(i = index; i < array_length - 1; i++){
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
        }
        /* Array indexes in C are in the range [0 - length-1]. Here 
           you are going outside array boundaries.
        */
        free(array[array_length]);
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to modify you codes to

```
void remove_element(char **array, int index, int array_length)
{
  int i;
  for(i = index; i < array_length - 1; i++){
      array[i] = array[i + 1];    //I don't understand what's purpose here
  }
  free_fragments(array);   //array[array_length] is a invalid pointer, out of range
}
```